# KeyDown in delphi XE7 requires shift to register

Tags: delphi, vcl

UPDATE:
*Another process on my machine was interfering with shortcut detections.*

In a VCL TStringgrid I want to copy the contents using “Ctrl+C" and/or "Ctrl+c”

Code snippet:

```
procedure TEditWaterFrame.sgSSPKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
    if (ssCtrl in Shift) AND ((Key = Ord('c')) OR (key = Ord('C'))) then  // this just won't work without me holding ssShift as well, I'm clueless...!
    begin
        ShowMessage('Ctrl+C pressed as keys');
        try
            Clipboard.AsText    := writeSSPToCSVString(#9);
        finally
            Clipboard.Free;
        end;
    end;

end;

// trying with keypress
procedure TEditWaterFrame.sgSSPKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
    if (Key = ^c) then  // this just won't work without me holding ssShift as well, I'm clueless...!
    begin
        ShowMessage('Ctrl+C pressed as char');
        try
            Clipboard.AsText    := writeSSPToCSVString(#9);
        finally
            Clipboard.Free;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

The two procedures above only run if ssCtrl + **ssShift** + c/C is pressed.
It does not trigger when ssShift is not pressed (i.e. Ctrl+c or Ctrl+C).

I am mystified!

Answer (score 5):

I created an empty VCL forms application, added a string grid to the main form, and implemented an event handler for its `OnKeyDown` event:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (ssCtrl in Shift) and (key = Ord('C')) then
    Beep;
end;
```

The computer sounded a beep when I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + C.

Something else in your program is handling that key press in your application.

Returning to the condition above, this will fire if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is down, irrespective of the state of the other modifier keys. So you will also respond to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> C, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> C and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> C. I doubt that you want to do that. So you might write the condition as:

```
if (Shift*[ssCtrl,ssShift,ssAlt]=[ssCtrl]) and (key = Ord('C')) then
```

---

Note that there were a number of errors in your code:

- The calls to `Clipboard.Free` will destroy a shared object that you don't own. You must not do this. Remove those calls.
- The logic of your `if` statement was wrong. The test `Key = Ord('c')` is always false. When the key is pressed, irrespective of the state of the modifier keys, you must test for the upper case ordinal, `Key = Ord('C')`.
- Your condition is of the form `if a and b or c`. Operator precedence means this is evaluated as `if (a and b) or c`. That's not what you intended.

All of this is moot, since your condition evaluates `True` when the C key is pressed irrespective of the modifier state. The conclusion remains the same: something else is handling <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + C and stopping that key down event reaching your code.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the logical errors.
I had `if a and (b or c)` originally, but that failed to produce a results, so I plainly played around until the statement triggered.
I'll post solution if I find it.

Comment: Please don't post a solution because it will rely on information that is not in the question. There can be nothing more to add to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The following works just fine for me when pressing <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>:

```
procedure TEditWaterFrame.sgSSPKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #3) then // ^c also works
  begin
    ShowMessage('Ctrl+C pressed');
    ...
  end;
end;
```

If you want *only* <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>, and not <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL+ALT+C</kbd>, etc, you will have to use `Get(Async)KeyState()` to make sure the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> keys are not also being pressed:

```
procedure TEditWaterFrame.sgSSPKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #3) then // ^c also works
  begin
    if (GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) = 0) and (GetKeyState(VK_MENU) == 0) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Ctrl+C pressed');
      ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure TEditWaterFrame.sgSSPKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #3) then // ^c also works
  begin
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) >= 0) and (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU) >= 0) then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Ctrl+C pressed');
      ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```